# HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized token '嬀崀'

Tags: java, resttemplate, httpentity

I am calling an endpoint via RestTemplate as follows:

```
   SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();
   SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
   HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
   ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);

   HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestJson, headers());
   Object[] response = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, entity, Object[].class);
```

I have verified that the JSON String in the `entity` object is valid by copying it and using it in a cURL request to the same endpoint without any error. The same headers and authorization token were used in this request too.

When I execute the POST, I get back the following error:

```
Error while extracting response for type [class [Ljava.lang.Object;] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-16]
```

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized token '嬀崀': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token '嬀崀': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
     at [Source: (InputStreamReader); line: 1, column: 3]
```

My `accept` and `content-type` headers are both set to `application/json`. From examining the output from cURL, I see that there are no Chinese characters in the response body.

The response headers are as follows:

```
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date → xxx
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
Vary →Accept-Encoding
```

When I make the request with the `responseType` set to `String.class` or `Object.class`, the response is Chinese characters:

```
restTemplate.postForObject(uri, entity, String.class);
嬀崀
```

I am expecting that this call should return an empty array `[]`.

When I change the `requestJson` String to one which should serve back a non-empty array, I get back hundreds of Chinese characters instead of just two.

How can I decode the response to get valid data like when I use cURL?

edit:

I'm not sure how this is related, but the bytecode for the chars in an empty array `[]` are 91 and 93, and the bytecode for the two Chinese characters is 0, 91, 0, 93.

Comment: any accept headers set to use UTF-16?

Comment: @MarcStroebel My `accept` and `content-type` request headers are both set to `application/json`

Comment: @MarcStroebel Same goes for "application/json;charset=UTF-8" for ACCEPT, CONTENT_TYPE, and CONTENT_ENCODING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is serving back UTF-8 content when I call it from cURL, but when I call the API programmatically it is serving back UTF-16LE despite my request headers asking for UTF-8 explicitly.

I will need to do some de-/en-coding games, but the following allows me to observe the valid, expected response JSON:

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, entity, byte[].class);
   
byte[] bytes = responseEntity.getBody();

String json = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);

FooBar[] fooBar = objectMapper.readValue(json, FooBar[].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the response from restTemplate is returned as a String of Chinese characters not an array. The first error you posted seems to indicate that the issue is with extracting the response into an `Object[]`. If the response from the restTemplate is actually a String, then that would explain the second error as well. The RestTemplate was expecting to parse an array but instead received the String `嬀崀`. That's why changing the response type to `String.class` seems to work.

If you're expecting a JSON array back from the api you're calling, then I would double check the response from the api you're calling. Otherwise, I would suggest using `String.class` instead.

Edited:
It's possible that the restTemplate is parsing the response using the `utf-16` charset and the server is encoding the response using the `utf-8` charset. Like you've posted in the description, those characters seem to have the same bytecode. Maybe changing the expected charset in the restTemplate to `utf-8` will resolve your problem.

Comment: The response from the endpoint is expected to be an empty array `[]` but it's being decoded in my code (incorrectly) as Chinese characters.

Comment: The response is valid JSON. I was just using String.class to cast as wide a net as possible to ensure I didn't throw a mapping exception to a DTO.

Comment: oh! sorry, I thought you were expecting Chinese characters in the array or something. I don't know the values of the character encodings of utf-8 vs utf-16, but it looks like the charset on the response from curl is utf-8 and the charset on the response from the restTemplate is utf-16. Maybe the representation of an empty array is translated into those chinese characters in the other charset?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use UTF16. HTTP Spec says ASCII, and many use UTF8.  The error points this out with `charset=utf-16` in it. Try setting the encoding header on the request.

What you're seeing, as you noted with the char codes, is exactly the result expected when using UTF16 because each char is 2 bytes.

Comment: Ok I set these request headers: ACCEPT, CONTENT_TYPE, and CONTENT_ENCODING to the value of `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`, however the error message served back is still `Error while extracting response for type [class java.lang.Object] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-16]`

Comment: Assuming you have control of the API server, make sure it's not forcing UTF16.

Comment: When I hit the exact same API via curl, I see that the response header is: `Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: We'd need more info..but that's where you should be looking: why are you getting a UTF16 encoded response, when headers seem to be set right.